# Regex for Forename Surname OR Mr & Mrs Surname (or Mrs & Mrs, etc.)

Tags: regex

I'm using this regex for some basic name validation

```
^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]*([-' ][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]*)*$
```

However I'd like to also allow `Mr & Mrs Bobble` as valid.  My current regex only allows a single space between character groups and I'm not sure how to allow `<space>&<space> or <space>`

Comment: Try `^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]*(?:(?: & |[-' ])[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]*)*$`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/1JPnrE/1).

Comment: not used non-capturing groups or the "OR" either :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]*(?:(?: & |[-' ])[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]*)*$
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1JPnrE/1)

The [non-capturing group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-what-does-do) `(?: & |[-' ])` matches either a space, `&`, space or a `-`, `'` or a single space. Non-capturing groups are used when the text they match won't be accessed after the match is found, so, in this case, all groups should be non-capturing: `(?: & |[-' ])` groups two alternatives with the `|` [alternation operator](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) and `(?:(?: & |[-' ])[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]*)` groups a quantified sequence of patterns.

If you mean to match any whitespace, replace the literal spaces in the pattern with `\s`.